# Exporting unfinished torrents data and import them again

Tags: windows-8, bittorrent, utorrent

I am using `uTorrent  3.4.2` as my bittorrent client.

Recently due to some issue I am planning to reinstall a fresh copy of windows.

Issue is currently there nay many torrent added to the list and also some of them have completed a good amount of download. So in normal case if I reinstall windows I lose all this progress and also all the torrent waiting in queue.

Is there a way I can export these torrents so I could import them again after reinstalling everything and continue where I left?

My all torrent files half completed and completed all in different drive. So reinstalling windows (formatting C) wont lost that but how to tell the `uTorrent` about the location of these unfinished files is the question.

Answer (score 1):

Torrent files are usually in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent` folder or where you installed your uTorrent application.
I have the method to delete torrent file. Right click -> Remove And -> Delete.torrent 
Then go to Recycle Bin and pull the torrent file to the Desktop. Then you can save it.
When you reinstall your windows. Install uTorrent and open .torrent. Save the torrent to the location(Set your download location) where your data is. qTorrent will run a check on your file(data) and resume where it stopped downloading.